# why default CacheManager is not getting in spring boot 3 and ehcache 3

Tags: spring-boot, ehcache-3

I'm using Spring Boot 3 to implement EhCache 3. It functions flawlessly in the spring boot embedded Tomcat server, however when I attempt to deploy it in the Tomcat server, the following problem is displayed.

> **Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/JCacheCacheConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cacheManager'
> parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'jCacheCacheManager'
> defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/JCacheCacheConfiguration.class]:
> Failed to instantiate [javax.cache.CacheManager]: Factory method
> 'jCacheCacheManager' threw exception with message: Cache 'cache'
> creation in EhcacheManager failed.**

adding details of code

build.gradle
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-cache'
implementation group: 'javax.cache', name: 'cache-api', version: '1.1.1'
implementation group: 'org.ehcache', name: 'ehcache', version: '3.10.8'

application.properties
spring.cache.jcache.config=classpath:ehcache.xml
spring.cache.jcache.provider=org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider

also added @EnableCaching in Application class.

I'm getting the above error when I try to autowire CacheManager. Why is it not getting through? The CacheManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default ehcache uses javax.cache but with Spring Boot 3 you need to use jakarta instead of javax. There is a fix for this in Ehcache 3.10:
https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/releases/tag/v3.10.0

Remove:

```
implementation group: 'javax.cache', name: 'cache-api', version: '1.1.1'
```

Add classifier to ehcache dependency:

```
implementation "org.ehcache:ehcache:3.10.8:jakarta"
```